# How to recycle a .NET Core app in IIS without losing subscriptions and sessions?

Tags: iis, .net-core, server, client

I am experiencing some challenges within .NET Core. We have three applications:

1. A UWP application (client).
2. A .NET Core Server (server A).
3. Another server (server B).

The **client** will connect via SignalR to **Server A**. **Server A** connects via another protocol to **server B**. When the situation changes on **Server B** it will send a notification to **Server A** and **Server A** will send this back to the client. **Server A** must keep track and know his subscriptions and sessions to **Server B**. For this I am using the interface implementation of IHostedService, which works fine for long running tasks.

This is where the problem occurs, when the .NET application is running in IIS and there occurs a recycle, all the subscriptions and sessions will be lost and I don't know how to solve this.

How can I solve my problem and still make use of .NET Core?

Comment: I see many problems. In the case the server A is down. All UWP clients must reconnect by them self to the server. You cannot initiate this again from server. So you have to add a reconnecting mechanisme into your UWP client. I did this once, where I tried to reconnect every 5 seconds. Additinallyyou need a mechansime that each client has an unique id. So you need an authentication mechansime.

Comment: Maybe you should look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dn277317%28v%3dvs.118%29